# notification can't go current activity

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

In my notification, I want to start current activity when click in pending intent. In google, many ways found and I tried many times, it didn't work. here is my code,

```
          public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
     super.onStart(intent, startId);

     String startTime = intent.getStringExtra("Strar_time");

     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "reminder", when);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.vibrate = new long[]{100, 200, 100, 500};
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Goo.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP/* | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP*/);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent , 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "It's about time", "Your time is "+startTime, contentIntent);
        notification.contentIntent=contentIntent;
        nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
        NOTIF_ID++;
        Log.i("NotiID",NOTIF_ID+"");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function given below,

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.launch_icon;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = null;

    notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one working way I found so far is to make a dummy activity, start it and finish it in onRusume(). However this technique only bring application to front and do not start application when it is closed.
Then I used following workaround to bring application on front if it is alive in background otherwise  start it.

**Manifest:**

```
<application>
.
.
.
 <activity
 android:name=".DummyActivity"
 />

.
.
</application>
```

**In code:**

```
public class DummyActivity{

public static boolean isAppAlive;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      // start application if it is not alive
       if(!isAppAlive){
         PackageManager  pmi = getPackageManager();
         Intent intent = pmi.getLaunchIntentForPackage(Your applications package name);                    
          if (intent != null){
              startActivity(intent);
           }

      }
    finish();
    }
```

In your main activity's onCreateMethod.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  DummyActivity.isAppAlive = true;
}
```

It is obvious that when your application is fully closed, isAppAlive will restore to its default value which is false. Thus application will be start.